# Getting error "An operation on a socket could not be performed..." with XAMPP and Windows again and again

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have a PHP application which is running under XAMPP (Windows Environment : Windows server 2012).

Now very often I am getting an error while trying to login via a MySql web client (adminer **https://www.adminer.org/**) as follow;

**An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.**

I've found one solution which describes restarting the **physical server (not xampp)**. And it worked. But in the very next day it happened again. And once again I restarted it but in a few interval the error is coming again and again.

[image: Error at adminer]

FYI;

1. Restarting XAMPP is not working
2. Restarting MySql server is not working
3. Only if I restart physical server then it is working for a while.
4. The server was working fine along with all current configuration from last 6 months and this problem starts to come from last few days only.

In the server;

1. The CPU consumption is around 30% to 40% when top load
2. RAM consumption on average 40% to 50%
3. The HDD is 90GB in which 10GB to 12GB is free still (only one drive is there that is C)

I am not getting properly the reason of the error.

Comment: Seems like a port issue. Did you tried changing tcp port limit? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196271/when-you-try-to-connect-from-tcp-ports-greater-than-5000-you-receive-t

Comment: Apache is running on port 80 and mysql is 3306 which is by default. Do I need to change port limit for this default configuration? And if it is port limit issue then why is it not happening always rather becomes fine after physical server restart for few hours?

Comment: In 2012 the port limit should not be the issue, your PC may be making too many outgoing requests causing port exhaustion, inspect your network requests, your PC may also be infected with a virus which is making the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Windows server 2012 has limit of outbound ports of 5000. The OS is trying to establish an outbound TCP connection from a port with a number greater than 5000 in your case.

Here's how to reconfigure OS to raise the limit https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/196271/when-you-try-to-connect-from-tcp-ports-greater-than-5000-you-receive-t

The real solution, though is to introduce connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Skype and XAMPP at the same time? If yes, try disabling Skype and re-run XAMPP.